# Segmentation Fault - Difficulty with assigning a class

Tags: c++, dictionary, artificial-intelligence, c++14

I am trying to assign my class `DictObj` to create a new instance of the class. What it wants to do, is to have a pointer to the class created, rather than the actual Object.

If I am to do what it likes, and have:
`DictObj * d;`, and then say something like, "`d->load();`", it gives me difficulty when assigning a string to a string. Such as with, assuming word is of type `string`, `word = a;`, where a is also a string passed as a parameter of the same type (no pointers or references). It gives me a segmentation fault when I do this.

Any suggestions as to how to fix this problem? Below, I will show a sample of the code:

P.S. I know I am  adding "Dicts.cpp", even though I am not supposed to. It is giving me an error of

> /tmp/ccEFPwDS.o: In function 'main':
>   /home/courtneymaroney/Desktop/Courtney/Documents/AI/NEW/main.cpp:60: undefined reference to `DictObj::load()`

ACTUAL CODE:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<thread>
#include<cassert>
#include<exception>
#include"Directory.hpp"
#include"Dicts.cpp"
#include"Tests.hpp"

int main() {
  cout << "Hello\n\n";
  DictObj * d;
  d->load();
  return 0;
}
```

Here is Dicts.cpp

```
void DictObj::setW(string a)
{
    word = a;
}
```

This gives me a segmentation fault when it runs the method:

```
void DictObj::load()
{
    string temp;
    cout <<"Type New Word: ";
    getline(cin, temp);
    cin >> temp;

    setW(temp);
```

the code goes on, but the error is at "setW(temp)"

IF I try to make a new DictObj in the main class, as expected, then it gives me an error

Code:

```
int main() {
    cout << "Hello\n\n";
    DictObj d = new DictObj();
    d.load();
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -c "main.cpp" (in directory:         /home/courtneymaroney/Desktop/Courtney/Documents/AI/NEW)
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:59:26: error: conversion from ‘DictObj*’ to non-scalar type     ‘DictObj’ requested
  DictObj d = new DictObj();
                      ^
Compilation failed.
```

ALSO: My compilation code is as follows (I am using Geany)

`g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -c "%f"`

My Build code is as follows:

`g++ -g -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -lpthread  -o "%e"  "%f"`

DEFINITION of DictObj class:

```
class DictObj
{
    public:
       DictObj();
       DictObj(const DictObj&);
       void load();
       void setW(string);
   private:
       string word; 
};
```

Comment: `DictObj* d = new DictObj(); d->load();`

Comment: `DictObj d; d.load();` -- There is no need for `new` to create an object.

Comment: I still got a segmentation fault on both of those. `Hello

Segmentation fault (core dumped)


------------------
(program exited with code: 139)
Press return to continue


`

Comment: This is not your complete code, as you didn't post the definition of your `DictObj` constructor or your assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

Your first version `DictObj * d; d->load();` crashes since you dereference non-initialized pointer `d`. Hence, since `d` does not point to a valid object, `d->load()` will result in undefined behaviour (and most likely in a crash).

Your second version simply does not compile because you assign a pointer value to an object value. Write either `DictObj* d = new DictObj(); d->load()` or `DictObj d; d.load()`.

See the following code, which compiles and does not crash:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::string;

class DictObj
{
public:
    DictObj() {};
    DictObj(const DictObj&);
    void load() {
        string temp;
        std::cout <<"Type New Word: ";
        getline(std::cin, temp);
        std::cin >> temp;
        setW(temp);
    };
    void setW(string a)
        {
            word = a;
        };

private:
    string word;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    DictObj d;
    d.load();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Got segmentation faults with it. `Hello

Segmentation fault (core dumped)


------------------
(program exited with code: 139)
Press return to continue


`

Comment: Please show the definition of your `DictObj`-class.

Comment: Hm - cannot reproduce; please try my code; if this works, then the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: I will try your code. I didn't put argc and such, so maybe that will work?

Comment: `argc` should not make a difference.

Comment: Why are you doing a `getline` and also `std::cin` on the same stream?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: right; it's from the OP's code; I did not ask for as I don't think it is the root of the described problem.

Comment: It didn't make a difference. I have Dict.cpp in a separate file: Directory.hpp is the file where the main classes are, and Dict.cpp is just one of the definitions of a class. Maybe there is a problem with that? Can I have help with an explanation?

Comment: If you put the code above in one file, e.g. `simple.cpp`, (no header, no other files); does it then compile and run correctly? Please try out; otherwise it's rather hard to make further assumptions.

Comment: That one works fine. Like I said, it may have something to do with the fact that I have Dicts.cpp named differently than Directory.hpp. I will try to put that in and see how it works.

Comment: I used GDB, and it has a problem at this line, when making the constructor: `DictObj::DictObj() {}`

Comment: FOUND: It is having a problem creating a new element in a vector. SOLUTION?: need to create a new vector object?

Comment: IT MAY BE A LOOP- I may need to define the vector as a template, since it is calling `vector<DictObj> posDict;` when it creates a new DictObj

Answer (score 0):

USELESS QUSTION, AFTERALL.

I have found that the most possible problem with the code is that I am using Class Definitions to create Class Definitions of the same Class Definition. I.E.
in the class DictObj, I am defining a variable of type DictObj in the constructor. I will have to rewrite the class to separate the vectors (which is most of it) and the base DictObj nodes (the non-vectors).

Boo hoo.

Stupidity on my part.

I guess the lesson to be learned is NEVER EVER EVER DEFINE YOUR CLASS WITHIN A CLASS IN THE CONSTRUCTOR WHEN MAKING A NEW OBJECT.

At least I learned a valuable lesson!